# Bizzarre and intermittent error occuring in PHP script

Tags: php, apache, opcache

Now, this error is intermittent and easy to reproduce. Yes, I do mean it is easy to reproduce. The problem is that there isn't a pattern. The IDs for which it throws the error is consistent until I reset the opcache.

**EDIT:** Further research points to the op-cache. Disabling the op-cache solves the problem. Upping the RAM the op-cache can use only delays the script failure. I have been using [OpCacheGUI](https://github.com/PeeHaa/OpCacheGUI) to monitor the op-cache for a few days now and I rarely saw it use more than 20MB. This is an internal program that doesn't require speed so I'm just going to disable it.

Setup:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 (built: Jul  7 2014 16:34:16)
- Zend Engine v2.5.0
- Zend OPcache v7.0.3

The error:

> [UNK][2014-07-11 14:34:31-0400]Fatal Error(1):Cannot call private sql_class::__construct() in /var/www/html/.../classes/script.class.php(8)
>   URI: /.../js/getMessages.php?script=152
>   #0 default_error_handler() called at[/var/www/html/.../libconfig.php:122]
>   #1 shutdown() called atUnknown

getMessages.php:

```
<?php
define('NO_FORM_KEY',1);
require_once '../libconfig.php';
PackageManager::requireClassOnce('io.cachefile');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$etag=md5(implode(',',$_GET));
$cache=new CacheFile(CACHE.'/getMessages'.$_GET['script'].'.json',300,$etag);
if(!$cache->hasExpired()){
    $cache->readToOutput();
    exit;
}
$model=new mix_message(); // This class also extends sql_class
$script=new mix_script();
$script->load($_GET['script']);
$path='/mixer/message/'.mix_message::getBaseMessagePath($script);
$model->trackChanges(false);
$model->setScriptId($_GET['script']);
$model->find();
ob_start();
while($model->loadNext()){
    echo json_encode($path.$model->getId().'.mp3').',';
}
$cache->putContents('['.substr(ob_get_clean(),0,-1).']');
$cache->readToOutput();
```

The `mix_script` constructor:

```
5 class mix_script extends sql_class{
7    public function __construct(){
8       parent::__construct('scripts',
9           array(
10              'script_id',
11              'script_name',
12              'script_text',
...
20              'lgroup_path',
21              'pack_id'
22          ),
23          array(
...
35           PDO::PARAM_INT),
36          'script_id');
37      $this->init();
38  }
```

`sql_class`:

```
6   public function __construct($table,array $columns,array $colTypes,$pkey){
7       parent::__construct($table,array_combine($columns,$colTypes),$pkey,db_get_connection(),true);
8   }
```

`sql_class`'s parent for those curious:

```
public function __construct($table,array $columns,$pkey,$db,$trackChanges=false){
    $this->table=$table;
    $this->columns=$columns;
    $this->pkey=$pkey;
    $this->db=$db;
    $this->data=$trackChanges?new ChangeTrackingPropertyList:new PropertyList;
    $this->trackChanges=$trackChanges;
}
```

Comment: It's complaining about line 8 in `sql_class` even though it's just a `}`?  Is that a typo?  Also, the folks at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) might be able to contribute.

Comment: It's complaining about line 8 in `mix_script` which calls the `sql_class` constructor.

Comment: What really catches my eye is this: `Cannot call private sql_class::__construct()`.  Specifically the part where it thinks `__construct()` is `private`.
Do you have *any* classes that have a `private` constructors?

Comment: @Llama: None of the constructors in the call chain are private.

Comment: @JakeGould: Is there a way to test for that issue?

Comment: I'm just going to disable the op-cache. I disabled it and the script worked perfect. Turned it back on and the script started messing up again. Upped the op-cache memory to 256MB, even though it rarely used more than 20MB, and the script took longer to fail, but eventually did.